# Выборка значений нескольких полей из базы с занесением в одну переменную

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Допустим, есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT `street`, `house`, `apartment` FROM `table`
```

Могу ли я как-то поместить все 3 значения в 1 переменную `address`?

Comment: SQL какой ? Может вам надо их склеить ? тогда придет на помощь функция concat (которая правда не везде одинакова, в некоторых СУБД следует использовать их средства конкатенации строк, например оператор `||`)

Comment: вы пробовали так? $result= mysql_query('SELECT `street`, `house`, `apartment` FROM `table`'); while($address = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {echo $address['street'];} и тд?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте соединение строк:

1. Oracle:

   ```
   select street || ' ' || house || ' ' || apartment as address
   from table
   ```
2. MySQL:

   ```
   select concat(street, ' ', house, ' ', apartment) as address
   from table
   ```

   или

   ```
   select concat_ws(' ', street, house, apartment) as address
   from table
   ```